# Uploading to S3 bucket Swift 3 issue

Tags: ios, swift

```
func startUploadingImage() {

    var localFileName:String?

// Issue #1: This here causes a segmentation fault 11 - Worked completely fine in swift 2.3
    if let imageToUploadUrl = selectedImageUrl {

        let phResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [imageToUploadUrl], options: nil)
        localFileName = phResult.firstObject?.fileManager
    }

    if localFileName == nil {
        return
    }

    // Configure AWS Cognito Credentials
    let myIdentityPoolId = ""

    let credentialsProvider:AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType:AWSRegionType.euWest1, identityPoolId: myIdentityPoolId)

    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region:AWSRegionType.euWest1, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)

    AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

    // Set up AWS Transfer Manager Request
    let S3BucketName = ""

    let remoteName = localFileName!
    print(remoteName)
    let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()
    uploadRequest?.body = generateImageUrl(remoteName)
    uploadRequest?.key = remoteName
    uploadRequest?.bucket = S3BucketName
    uploadRequest?.contentType = "image/jpeg"

    let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.default()

    // Perform file upload

// #issue 2: Here I recieve an error of ambiguous reference to member 'continue' 

    transferManager.upload(uploadRequest).continue {
        task -> AnyObject! in

        if let error = task.error {
            print("Upload failed with error: (\(error.localizedDescription))")
        }

        if let exception = task.exception {
            print("Upload failed with exception (\(exception))")
        }

        if task.result != nil {

            let s3URL = URL(string: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/\(S3BucketName)/\(uploadRequest.key!)")!
            print("Uploaded to:\n\(s3URL)")

            // Remove locally stored file
            self.remoteImageWithUrl(uploadRequest.key!)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.submitImageToDatabase("https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/\(S3BucketName)/\(uploadRequest.key!)")
            }

        }
        else {
            print("Unexpected empty result.")
        }
        return nil
    }

}
```

Had a look at the AWS docs but can't seem to find nothing that's been updated since swift 3 (at least not that I can find).  Most of it is written in Obj-c anyway which doesn't help.

I also seem to have the issues `No such Module 'AWSS3'` and `No such Module 'AWSCore'` even though they run fine when the project is built and i can cmd click to see the files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
func uploadButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if documentImageView.image == nil {
       // Do something to wake up user :) 
    } else {
        let image = documentImageView.image!
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let path = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent("\(imageName!).jpeg")
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.99)
        fileManager.createFile(atPath: path as String, contents: imageData, attributes: nil)

        let fileUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        var uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()
        uploadRequest?.bucket = "BucketName"
        uploadRequest?.key = "key.jpeg"
        uploadRequest?.contentType = "image/jpeg"
        uploadRequest?.body = fileUrl as URL!
        uploadRequest?.serverSideEncryption = AWSS3ServerSideEncryption.awsKms
        uploadRequest?.uploadProgress = { (bytesSent, totalBytesSent, totalBytesExpectedToSend) -> Void in
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.amountUploaded = totalBytesSent // To show the updating data status in label.
                self.fileSize = totalBytesExpectedToSend
            })
        }

        let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.default()
        transferManager?.upload(uploadRequest).continue(with: AWSExecutor.mainThread(), withSuccessBlock: { (taskk: AWSTask) -> Any? in
            if taskk.error != nil {
               // Error.
            } else {
                // Do something with your result.
            }
            return nil
        })
    }
}
```

This is the complete code to upload an image to Amazon S3 written in **swift 3** . TO configure your cognate identity pool add following code in app delegate.

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    customiseAppearance()

    let credentialsProvider =AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType:"YOUR REGION",identityPoolId:"YOUR POOL ID")
    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region:"YOUR REGION",    credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)
    AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
    return true
}
```

Let me answer to this error No such Module 'AWSS3' and No such Module 'AWSCore' , Check whether you added the AWSS3 framework and AWSCore framework in bridging header file like

```
#import <AWSCore/AWSCore.h>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: I know this was a while back but, in this case, what is imageName? where `let path =`...

Comment: In my case `imageName` is the variable I used to store the image name which is got from user. So you can your own name as per you want. Like this `let path = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent("NameYouWant.jpeg")`

Comment: Just one last thing to clarify, if `uploadRequest?.key = "key.jpeg"` is the name of the file that is saved inside s3, what is `imageName`? Is it the temporary name of the file that is saved inside the directory of the app? Does the file name need to be different every time an image is saved to s3, or can it remain the same?

Comment: Yes  you are correct `imageName` is used to save your selected image in `documentDirectory` locally. You can use same for all images no need to change, since you are not going to  do anything with that locally saved image. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Update cocoapods to 1.0.0 version

> **gem list | grep cocoa**
>
> cocoapods (1.0.0)

Comment: I'm using 1.0.1 version

Answer (score 0):

We should use **AWSS3TransferUtility** now because AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest is **deprecated**, here is the jpeg upload function in **Swift 4.2** but it can be easily changed for any data type:

```
func uploadS3(image: UIImage,
              name: String,
              progressHandler: @escaping (Progress) -> Void,
              completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {

    guard let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, Constants.uploadImageQuality) else {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completionHandler(NetErrors.imageFormatError) // Replace your error
        }
        return
    }

    let credentialsProvider = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(accessKey: Constants.accessKeyS3, secretKey: Constants.secretKeyS3)
    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: Constants.regionS3, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
    AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
    let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression()
    expression.progressBlock = { task, progress in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            progressHandler(progress)
        }
    }

    AWSS3TransferUtility.default().uploadData(
        data,
        bucket: Constants.bucketS3,
        key: name,
        contentType: "image/jpg",
        expression: expression) { task, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completionHandler(error)
            }
            print("Success")

        }.continueWith { task -> AnyObject? in
            if let error = task.error {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completionHandler(error)
                }
            }
            return nil
    }
}
```

Do not forget to define or change **Constants** in the code. If you don't want to give public access, you should also define a user in IAM, and put this code in your bucket policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "S3AccessPolicy",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "GiveAppPutAccess",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/YOUR_USER"
      },
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR_BUCKET/*"
    }
  ]
}
```