# Upload file to remote server from iOS 11

Tags: mysql, swift, mongodb, azure, ios11

In an iOS 11 app, I have an audio file that I want to move to a database on a remote server. If I choose a cloud-store service, Firebase, Azure, and AWS are possible options. For a prototype, I want to use a server running MySQL or MongoDB. To upload to Mysql, for example, where do you suggest I start?

A web search returned these:

- [Swift upload audio file to Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43976824)
- [Uploading to S3 bucket Swift 3 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015552)
- [Unable to upload images in ios 11.0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46882548)

But it's not exactly what I want. I am trying to prototype an app that records an audio file and upload it, so I'm looking for a simple solution if any of you have a suggestion.

Comment: normally you'd need a web application in front of the database so you can make a HTTP request to transfer the file, then the application receives the request, processes it and saves the file

Comment: I expect to use a PHP web service to access the database running on Linux box.

Comment: ok well that should work nicely then. Plenty of examples of uploading files using PHP online already. What have you tried? What are you stuck with, exactly?

Comment: Here is what i'm starting with, If you think this is a good start I'll go down this road and post more details if I run into an issue.: [Learn NSURLSession using Swift Part 3— Upload

](https://medium.com/swift-programming/learn-nsurlsession-using-swift-part-3-upload-3a5be9a69950) and [How to upload images using swift 2: send multipart post request](http://www.kaleidosblog.com/how-to-upload-images-using-swift-2-send-multipart-post-request)

Comment: I don't know any Swift so I can't comment, I'm afraid. You certainly need to build a multi-part HTTP request, but whether that's the most efficient way to do in Swift I don't know - these days I'd kind of expect there to be some sort of library which would make it less of a manual string-concatenation task, certainly that's true in .NET and other popular languages.